# Howto preg_replace a specific symbol within parentheses?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I got a bunch of strings like this one:

```
(50 μg/ml); (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 μg/ml) (sub-diploid DNA fraction) (p<0.05)
```

What I want to do with PHP now is to replace the "<" in the last parentheses so it will look like:

```
(p&#60;0.05)
```

I actually got tired and frustrated from googling so please help me out with that. Just need a php preg replace function which finds the less than and greater than symbols within parenthesis of a string and replace it with it's ASCII code.

Comment: Use `echo htmlentities(str_replace("<", "&#60;", $str));`

Comment: can you show the full syntax of the preg_replace  for this (50 μg/ml); (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 μg/ml) (sub-diploid DNA fraction) (p<0.05)

Comment: I was trying preg_replace("#\((.<?)\)#", "&#60;", $str);, but it is not working. @YagnikDetroja

Comment: You could search [`(?:\(|\G(?<!^))[^)<]*+\K<`](https://regex101.com/r/vL5vV1/1) and replace however you want to

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is work.

```
$str="p&#60;0.05"; 
$s1=html_entity_decode(str_replace("<", "&#60;", $str));
echo $s1;
```

Or

```
$s1 = html_entity_decode($str);
```

Comment: I already said , what if the string contains HTML tags inside it.Your solution will also replace the greater than and less than symbols associated with HTML tags.I tried it. The same thing happens, I want regular expression search and replace for it. @Yagnik Detroja

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = '(50 > µg/ml); (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 µg/ml) (sub-diploid DNA fraction) (p<0.05)';
$str = preg_replace('/(\([^<]+)<([^)]+\))/', '$1&#60;$2', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(\([^>]+)>([^)]+\))/', '$1&#62;$2', $str);
echo $str;
```

**Output:**

```
(50 &#62; µg/ml); (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 µg/ml) (sub-diploid DNA fraction) (p&#60;0.05)
```

Comment: It works. But can't we make the regex more specific so that it will not look for a particular pattern inside parenthesis. I mean it will replace any lower than or greater than characters within it. What you did is specified a pattern between two type of sets. @Toto

Comment: @DarkHorse: Please, edit your question and add some sample input strings and expected result.

Comment: This is straight. I want to replace every greater than and smaller than symbols inside parenthesis in my string. @Toto

Comment: @DarkHorse: You have to run 2 preg_replace, see my edit.